# img alt attribute for "decorative" images

Tags: browser, cross-browser, screen-readers, section508

### A question for the truly [pedant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedant)

*I was looking through Chrome's Developer Tool's elements tab when something caught my eye and prompted this question.*

Though meaningful `alt` attributes on `img` tags are a necessary expectation for accessibility (`<img src="/path/to/beauty.png"`**alt="Olivia Culpo won the Miss USA 2012 contest"**`/>`), I have [seen it](http://www.standardista.com/standards/alternative-text-for-images-the-alt-attribute/#alt_di) [often](http://www.hhs.gov/web/policies/checklisthtml.html) [advised](http://www.jimthatcher.com/webcourse2.htm) that the `alt` attribute of "spacer", or other "decorative" images should be given a blank value: `<img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt`**=""**`/>`

**These questions are just for decorative images:**

- What happens if I declare the alt attribute, but don't *define* it:
  `<img src="/images/spacer.gif"`**alt**`/>`
- Of the two options, which is optimal (and why)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `<img src="..." alt />` through the validator, it throws an error. The `alt` attribute needs a value, even if it is null `alt=""`. Usually when an image doesn't have an alt, some assistive technology announces the path to the image.

So `<img src="..." alt />` is the same as `<img src="..." />`. Usually the word used is decorative vs trival, but it is probably the same idea. These type of images should have a null alt.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan B...which validator did you test against?

Answer (score 1):

Both will pass W3C validation but according to recommendations in WCAG 2.0 the preferred method is to define the attribute as:

```
<img src="" alt="" />
```

[See the following working note from the W3C.](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H67.html)